# How do I print a string containing a 0 character in the middle?

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I need to define an array of `char`s. One of the `char`s in the array must be 0.

I tried something like this:

```
array[i] = '0';
```

but when I send `array` to the output with:

```
cout << array << endl;
```

the 0 `char` is interpreted as a string separator, so only the part of array comprised between indices 0 and i-1 is printed.

How should I define the 0 character in such a way that array is printed as a whole sequence of chars, without interruptions?  Could the problem depend on the nature of `cout` (I mean, maybe my assignment of 0 `char` is correct, but the printing function has some weird behavior I have ignored)?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `cout << array << endl;` is C++.

Comment: `0` is a zero. `'0'` is the representation of a zero in the character set (eg, ascii).  In C, `'0'` is an int.  In c++, `'0'` is a char.  In either case, just remove the quotes.

Comment: you should use `array[i] = '\0'` which represent the end of string.

Comment: You want to store a null character (`'\0'`, not `'0'`) in an array, and then print the entire array, including the null character? The null character marks the end of a string. It rarely makes sense to print a null character; why are you trying to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Character literal (or named as character constant in C)  `'0'` is not the terminating zero of strings. It seems you used either `'\0'` or integer literal `0` instead of `'0'`. `'\0'` or 0 are indeed the terminating zero and has value 0 while `'0'` for example in ASCII has value 48.

Take into account that you wrote that you are programming in C but showed a C++ code snippet.:)

Answer (score 1):

```
array[i] = '0'; // ASCII code of 0 as a character goes in
array[i] = 0; // string terminator character, can also be written as '\0', same thing
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to send the ASCII character 0, you can write:

```
char a='0'
```

or

```
char a=48
```

The problem I still don't know how to solve is how to send the null byte to a serial port, because `0` or `\0` are the same and always interrupt the string!

Comment: Don't write `char a=48;`. It's much less clear than `char a='0';`, and it's not entirely portable (there are non-ASCII systems where `'0' != 48`).